# What is the new Frenzy status effect in MH4U?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

What is the new Frenzy status effect in Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate?  What does it do?  What causes it?  How can it be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Frenzy Virus**

Description:

> The Hunter becomes infected with a virus. It requires time to incubate, represented by a purple bar filling up below the Hunter's on-screen name. If the bar fills completely, the virus negates natural health recovery, meaning that the Hunter takes full damage from attacks without being able to heal back half of it. Additionally, all attacks which would cause the condition will deal extra damage while the virus is active. However, if the Hunter inflicts enough damage on a monster whilst the virus is incubating, they gain a 15% Affinity boost instead, as well as an immunity to infection for a short period of time.

Remedy:

> While incubating, the incubation can be delayed by consuming a Nulberry. The fully incubated virus can only be cured by prolonged exposure to a Panacea or waiting it out.

[source](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Status_Effects)

I can confirm this information is correct. The [Gore Magala](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Gore_Magala) and [Shagaru Magala](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Shagaru_Magala) are the primary monsters that deal this status effect. Additionally, infected monsters (ie. Infected Tigrex) will gain the ability to deal this status effect.

If the virus fully incubates and you get the debuff, it's easier to simply run to another area. The debuff should go away after a minute. Attempting to fight the monster with the incubated virus is a death wish, as many attacks do extra damage. A recent fight against Shagaru Magala showed me just how many attacks can one-shot me under this debuff.

Comment: You forgot to mention what causes the hunter to get it

Comment: I assumed that people know how status effects are generally applied by monsters.

Comment: not all attacks give the debuff.

Comment: If someone wants to post an answer detailing every attack that applies it, then feel free. However remember that infected monsters *also* have attacks that apply the debuff, and it would be simply too long to list them all. Generally, the idea is that "some attacks apply debuff", just like any other monster that applies status effects in the Monster Hunter series.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that standing in gore/shagaru magala's "virus clouds" while you have the debuff will slowly deal damage, though at least the "no natural health recovery" doesn't apply to this damage (i.e. you can heal it back)

Comment: If you Sleep in the bed at the base camp the effect goes away also
so you may wanna go there to get rid of the effect if you want to do it that way but if you get a certain effect from eating this method is useless to you