# How does the frenzy virus affect other monsters?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207571/) asks how the new frenzy virus affects hunters.

What effects does the virus have on infected monsters (that aren't Gore/Shagaru Magala)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, it modifies their movesets, both making them more aggressive, and giving them wholly new patterns. Frenzied Khezu, for instance, is able to do the "shoot three lightning balls along the ground" move twice in quick succession.

Comment: It should also be noted that Frenzied monsters can also apply the Frenzy status effect to hunters.